# Xml Serialization inside a collection

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

`XmlRoot` does not seem to work with classes that are contained within a collection. Here are the classes I have defined:

```
[XmlRoot("cars")]
public class CarCollection : Collection<Car>
{
}

[XmlRoot("car")]
public class Car
{
  [XmlAttribute("make")]
  public String Make { get; set; }

  [XmlAttribute("model")]
  public String Model { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to serialize these objects:

```
  CarCollection cars = new CarCollection();
  cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Ford", Model = "Mustang" });
  cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Honda", Model = "Accord" });
  cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Toyota", Model = "Tundra" });

  using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    XmlSerializer carSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarCollection));
    carSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, cars);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    String xml = null;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
      xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
      reader.Close();
    }
    memoryStream.Close();
  }
```

The xml after serialization looks like this:

```
<cars xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Car make="Ford" model="Mustang" />
  <Car make="Honda" model="Accord" />
  <Car make="Toyota" model="Tundra" />
</cars>
```

Notice the "C" in car is not lowercase. What do I need to change to make this happen? If I serialize the Car directly it comes out as I would expectg.

UPDATE: 
I found another workaround. I am not sure how much I like it but it will work for my case. If I create a custom class (see below) and have CarCollection derive from it the serialization works as I expected.

```
  public class XmlSerializableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, IXmlSerializable
  {
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
      return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
      bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
      reader.Read();
      if (wasEmpty)
      {
        return;
      }

      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

      while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
      {
        T t = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        this.Add(t);
      }

      if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
      {
        reader.ReadEndElement();
      }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
      XmlSerializer reqSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
      foreach (T t in this.Items)
      {
        reqSerializer.Serialize(writer, t);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you know why the workaround of inserting a custom XmlSerializableCollection<T> class causes the xml you want to be generated during serialization?

Comment: It works because I am serializing the child objects manually and it then respects the XMLRoot attribute on the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just markup the car with XmlType?

```
[XmlType("car")]
public class Car
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`XmlRootAttribute` only applies if the element is the root of the object graph being serialized, ie. the object you pass to the `XmlSerializer` instance.

To control serialization of collections, you would normally use the `XmlElementAttribute` to specify the element name to serialize the child objects with. Unfortunately, this attribute can only be applied to a field or property and not a class.

If you can expose your collection as a property of a class, you can use the attribute as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("cars")]
public class CarList
{
    [XmlElement("car")]
    public CarCollection Cars { get; set; }
}
```

With your code sample, produces the following result:

```
<cars xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <car make="Ford" model="Mustang" />
  <car make="Honda" model="Accord" />
  <car make="Toyota" model="Tundra" />
</cars>
```

It's a bit of a work-around, but it's the closest you can get without lots of custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a cop-out but I was able to make this work using the `DataContractSerializer` like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CarCollection cars = new CarCollection();
        cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Ford", Model = "Mustang" });
        cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Honda", Model = "Accord" });
        cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Toyota", Model = "Tundra" });

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer 
                = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(CarCollection));
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, cars);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            String xml = null;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
    }
}

[CollectionDataContract(Name = "cars")]
public class CarCollection : Collection<Car> { }

[DataContract(Name = "car")]
public class Car
{
    [DataMember(Name = "make")]
    public String Make { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "model")]
    public String Model { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<cars xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <car>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>Mustang</model>
  </car>
  <car>
    <make>Honda</make>
    <model>Accord</model>
  </car>
  <car>
    <make>Toyota</make>
    <model>Tundra</model>
  </car>
</cars>
```

Notice that the attributes on your types have changed to support the usage of `DataContractSerializer`.  I don't know if this is the direction that you want to go with this but I have found that in almost every case I prefer to use the `DataContractSerializer` in place of the older `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: That might work. I would just need to get the make and model properties to be attributes instead of child nodes.